# How to remove payment method step in checkout process in Magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.3

I have magento Open Source 2.3.2 setup my client don't want any payment method now. How to remove payment method step in checkout process. I just want to place order without selection payment method.

Any suggestion welcome in advanced.

Below is the exact representation of the requirement.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score -1):

To Disable a Payment Method in Magento 2:

**Step 1:** Edit **config.xml** file

**Step 2:** Edit **Observer.php** file

Step 1: Edit **config.xml** file
To disable the Payment Method Programmatically, firstly, you need to open the config.xml file and then add the following code to that file:

`<global>
    ...
    <events>
        <payment_method_is_active>
            <observers>
                <disable_paymentmethod>
                    <class>Vendor_Extension_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>paymentMethodIsActive</method>
                </disable_paymentmethod>
            </observers>
        </payment_method_is_active>
    </events>
    ...
</global>`

Step 2: Edit **Observer.php** file
In this step, the below code should be added in the Observer.php file

```html
<?php
class Vendor_Extension_Model_Observer {
    public function paymentMethodIsActive(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $method = $observer->getMethodInstance();
        
        if ($method->getCode() == 'payment_method_code') {
            
            if (condition) {
                $result = $observer->getResult();
                $result->isAvailable = false;
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer talks about M1 but the question is about M2

Comment: did you check in 2.3.2

Comment: This solution is only disable the particular payment method. But I am looking for the solution to skip the entire payment method step. Once the the shipping method process completed directly to place the order.